# Problem with an exercise: position and velocity of a thrown sphere with non uniform acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

You stand at the earth's surface, have an object, for example a sphere, of mass $ m_1 $ and throw it with a velocity $ v_1 $ into the atmosphere, perpendicular to the surface. Let $g$ at the surface be $ 9.81 {m \over s^2} $
Now I would like to compute the position and the velocity of the sphere after a time $t$.

Let $ x(t) $ be the position of the sphere at a time $ t $ then, one should have for $ t = 0 : $ $ x(0) = 6300km$ (radius of the earth) and $ x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} v_1 - g(t)t \ dt $ with $ g(t) = G* {m_2 \over x(t)^2} $,  $g$ is not constant as the sphere distances itself from the earth, therefore I need a $g(t)$!

I get the last equation  by observing $ F = m_1*g $ and $ F = G * {m_1 * m_e \over R^2} $ with $ m_e $ being the mass of the earth. $ R^2 $ is not constant and thus be replaced by $ x(t) $.

However this gets me into a lot of trouble as my final equation now looks like this:

$x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} v_1 - t* G * { m_e\over x(t)^2 } \ dt $. This approach doesn't look like it gets me anywhere, especially if I think about having $ v_1 = \sqrt{g*R} $;  $v_1$ being the first cosmic escape.

I don't really see my mistake in my approach, though it feels wrong. May someone show me or give me a hint, how to alter my approach so that I can get an x(t) for different given $ v_1 $ ? I would be really thankful.

EDIT 1: I think now $x(t) $ should be something of sorts:

$x(t) = {1 \over 2 } * G * {m_e \over x^2 (t) } + v_1 * t $ ;

however this doesn't seem to help either...

Comment: Do you intend to take account of rotation of the earth? Because that will obviously matter. Otherwise you have an "extremely eccentric elliptical orbit" - maybe you can figure it out with that hint (look for `vis viva equation`)

Comment: I think I will take the earth rotation into account at a later point in time as another exercise.
I have just started doing more physics recently, thus I would like to keep things "simple". 
The vis viva equation looks very interesting though :)
I will read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) alone, this can be determined from conservation of energy. You can also determine the velocity an object has at a certain position, but if you want to determine the motion diagram you have to solve Newton's equations
$$m\ddot{\mathbf a} = -G\frac{mM}{r^3}\mathbf r$$
which in spherical coordinates simplify to
$$\ddot r = -G\frac M{r^2},$$
but please don't ask me how to solve this, for my lazy answer will just be "numerically".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the equation you wrote down for $x(t)$ is not necessarily right depending on the acceleration. I think it assumes the decrease in velocity is simply $-at$, which is only true for constant acceleration. To do this right, you have to start with acceleration and work up to position. First, write down acceleration.

$$ a(t)= \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{dv}{dx}v= -G*\frac{m_e}{x(t)^2}$$

If acceleration were constant we could've integrated both sides easily. In this case we had to manipulate the expression for the acceleration to be able to separate the variables. If we move the $dx$ to the right side and integrate, we get 
$$ \frac{v(t)^2}{2} = G*\frac{m_e}{x(t)} + C_1.$$
You can separate this equation again after solving for $C_1$ and get 
$$ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2G*m_e}{x}+2C_1}}= dt$$

This integral is challenging, but it's also common enough that I was able to look it up quickly. Note that in the special case that $v_0$ is the escape velocity, $C_1$ vanishes completely and the integral becomes very easy to compute. So that makes some sense. Anyway, first put it into a slightly nicer form.
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2C_1}} \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{\frac{G*m_e}{C_1}+x}}= dt$$
Now use substitution. Define $x=u^2-\frac{Gm_e}{C_1}, dx=2udu.$ Plug this in, integrate, then sub back $x$ into the equation.
$$\int\frac{1}{2C_1} \frac{\left(u^2-\frac{Gm_e}{C_1}\right)2udu}{u}=\int dt$$

$$\frac{2u}{\sqrt{2C_1}} \left(\frac{u^2}{3}-\frac{Gm_e}{C_1}\right)=t+C_2$$
$$ \frac{2\sqrt{x+\frac{Gm_e}{C_1}}}{\sqrt{2C_1}} \left(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{Gm_e}{3C_1}-\frac{Gm_e}{C_1}\right)= t+C_2$$

I'm not actually sure how possible it would be to solve this in terms of $x$. But a good calculator certainly could solve this for you for any input $t$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I could follow all your steps, though I wonder, how one should handle $ C_1 $ and $ C_2 $.
Do they have a certain value? If yes, which one and how would you get those?

Comment: You get those by plugging in the initial conditions. When $C_1$ pops up, plug in $v(0)$ and $x(0)$ to find it's value. In the final expression, plug in $t=0$ and $x(0)$ to find $C_2$. If you don't know a numerical value for $v_0$, just keep it as $v_0$ and you get a $C_1$ value that depends on initial velocity. Just make sure to include that the most general solution can't have $v_0=v_{esc}$, because that changes the last differential equation you have to solve.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.  

I just try to get a better understanding of those matters, what happens for $v_1 $ to $v_5$, namely : $0 < v_1 < v_{firstcosmicvelocity} = v_2 < v_3 < v_4 = v_{secondcosmicvelocity} < v_5 $

I find it just difficult to get proper material as one can't even find something good on the internet. Most materials just cover the very basics, but as soon as one wants to get a better understanding, those materials fail :/

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field

Comment: @Floris, I fail to see what the inverse square law gravitational field has to do with my problem or how it takes MonkeysUncle's answer any further. May elaborate?

Comment: @Imago - isn't that the problem you are trying to solve? Motion of an object in an inverse square law field? The link gives the (very messy) inverse of the equation that MonkeysUncle derived - namely, $y(t)$; as such I thought it complemented the answer given here nicely.

Comment: @Floris, I begin to make the connection, though I guess I am still a good way away from understanding. 
I try to get the way to formulas, that describe $ v_i $ , i = 1,2,3,4,5 with:
$ 0 < v_1 < v_2 = v_{firstcosmicvelocity} < v_3 < v_4 = v_{secondcosmicvelocity} < v_5 $
Also find out the position x of the sphere at a given time t.
So far I can follow  MonkeysUncle's post to the end, but I find it hard to completely "nail" the problem.. so that I could say that I understood everything.
At least now I know how the sphere "behaves" for a given $v_i$ ...